# Database table protection from app perspective

Tags: database, security

could you please share your experience about one topic coming to my mind? Imagine that you have a SQL table (e.g. on Azure environment)
with columns UserID and Data (to keep is simple). Your application is selecting from this table through SELECT statement and providing
UsedID in GUID form of given user of the application. UserID is generated during installation, so this value is quite hard to guess.
But, if someone will have enough luck and effort to guess someone's other UserID and crack the app (decompilation in case of C#), so he will
know where to put the fake identity, he will be able to get data of other users. Is there any set of best practices (application and server side)
how minimalize risks or even better to be 100% safe? :D

thanks a lot for any insights!

Answer (score 0):

From the scenario you describe, an interested attacker does not even need to decompile the application; they can simply sniff their own network traffic, and replay requests containing the UserID until they find one (other than their own) that yields positive results. In addition, this is a possible avenue for SQL injection attacks, even without finding another UserID.

The fundamental idea behind this approach, however, is sound; using a unique, hard-to-guess token to identify users. This is essentially how most authentication schemes work, with the important difference that they use one-time, disposable tokens. That is, instead of using the UserID to authenticate, you would use a long, seemingly random string that can be somehow derived by both the client and server, that it used to authenticate a single connection and that connection only. Thus, instead of sending the UserID across the wire, the client sends the server a seemingly random string, which the server can use to determine that the user is who they say they are.

One way of doing this would be to use the UserID as the key to encrypt the current time, and pass that to the server. The server could then attempt to decrypt the passed string using the UserID; if the result is the current time, then the server knows that the client knows the UserID, without ever having to send the UserID over the wire. Of course, you would then need another identifier so that the server can know which UserID it needs to use, but this identifier does not need to be kept secret.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a per-client password and authenticate the client on the server with every inquiry.

This will limit any type of exposure to only the authenticated client.

Unless you have a way of validating each client's identity on the server with a shared secret (i.e. some sort of authentication scheme), whatever magic you attempt with the UserID obfuscation will be wasted effort.